# Is the salary range in the job advertisements real or an estimation?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Is the salary, or salary range that is shown below a job advertisement just an estimation by Stack Overflow? Or are those numbers provided by the advertiser?

Comment: It is data provided by the company advertising the position.

Comment: no its a real offer, its per year also

Comment: A job advertisement is not a job offer.  An offer comes after the interview process and does contain the actual salary offered.

Comment: Is the job description real or just an estimation ?

Comment: In my experience It's all relative (and or negotiable) until you sign the contract nothing is 100% real

Comment: of course, but if the company provides the numbers in the ad, it is at least a good starting point for the negotiation. If it would be just an estimation, based on whatever, then it might be even inappropriate to use those numbers in the further negotiation, especially if the range is very width

Comment: Yeah definitely a good starting point for the negotiation, I would love to see some analytics on the data, like what percentage of the job ads have a salary range

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The salary displayed on job listings (and in job ads) is entered directly by the hiring company.

It is the advertised salary, not an estimation.

As @PeterHadded mentioned, it is a yearly salary.

Comment: So it doesn't have to be real either.

Comment: But some of them say equity? AFAIK that would mean a $100,000/yr salary with equity means you're not getting all of that in cash (minus taxes of course) but some of that "value" would be included in gaining some ownership of the company, right? So cash compensation could actually be $50,000 and the rest could be them offering you stock. Is that a fair assumption?

Comment: @Simon equity comes in *addition* to the salary. The advertised salary shouldn't take equity into account.

Comment: @AurélienGasser Does it ever get taken it to account or are they good at following those rules?

Comment: @Tim As far as I know, we haven't received any report stating that this wasn't the case. But if it happens, please let us know by reporting the job listing.

Comment: @AurélienGasser is that super clear to the companies entering the salary?

Comment: @FilipHaglund It seems pretty clear to me, although that's subjective. As far as I know, it is the norm to have the yearly salary be independent from equity, which comes as an extra. [Here's a screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/hxo1mkA.png) of what the compensation inputs look like on the employer side.

Comment: @AurélienGasser I've learned from this site that the norm doesn't really exist when you cross borders and cultures. Maybe you could add a few words to the "Equity is provided as part of the compensation package" text? :)

Comment: @FilipHaglund Since it hasn't been an issue, I'm reluctant to change the copy *just yet*. But thanks for the suggestion, I will definitely keep it in mind, and will reconsider if we ever run into an issue with this.

Comment: @AurélienGasser I would certainly read that screen as meaning that equity was part of the compensation package amount entered in the lines above, not as something in addition to it.  (But maybe there is other stuff not shown in the screenshot that makes it clear that the "compensation amount" is not the "compensation package amount"?)

Comment: Not to mention that the range can just be absurd. I've seen job postings with 80-180k ranges.

Comment: @YowE3K there isn't anything additional in the UI. I start from the assumption that employers consider the equity as separate, but this assumption could be wrong. Additionally, and as mentioned above, I'm not aware of any instance of an employer mis-using the form. However, your concern is quite valid, and I have relayed it to the Talent team (who maintains the job post form).

Comment: @AurélienGasser I'm not sure about other countries, but here in Australia it would not be uncommon for an employer to work out what the total "package" was worth, then work out how much of that they would pay in the form of salary, how much in the form of superannuation, how much in the form of a company car, how much in the form of shares, etc.  So those type of questions need to be very explicit so that employers in different countries know what is expected to be entered.

Comment: @AurélienGasser Good that there's no confusion so far, but I think the wording could be tweaked — as is, the "Provides equity" checkbox is under a heading "Compensation", so easy to imagine companies saying "£X is the total package value, of which some is provided as equity". I think the fact that the number input is salary only should be more explicit ([something like this?](https://i.imgur.com/oBkOyuH.jpg)).  Not on Stack Overflow, but as YowE3K mentioned, I've experienced recruiters talking about it like this previously, in the UK also.

Answer (score 2):

An extra point to Aurélian's answer is that the salary is *before* taxes. In some countries it is common to see the *after tax* value for salaries, but they're a minority.